# Is there a way to visualize typeDB (Grakn) data with Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, graphql, kibana, graph-visualization, vaticle-typedb

I want to visualize data that I will be storing in TypeDB. How can I visualize that data in Kibana? Or is there any other opensource visualization tool that supports connectivity with TypeDB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The official visualiser for TypeDB is [TypeDB Studio](https://github.com/vaticle/typedb-studio). Just download the [latest release](https://github.com/vaticle/typedb-studio/releases) and you should be ready to go.

TypeDB Studio is a graph visualiser, which will give the maximum benefit for  visualising the graph data in TypeDB.

Answer (score -1):

if typedb has an api, which I am not clear on if it does or not after reading their site, then you can use Logstash to get data from it and send to Elasticsearch

Comment: I have not found any API from typeDB using which I can get data from typeDB. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You can retrieve data from TypeDB using Python, Java, NodeJS and a number of other languages using the drivers/clients available on the Vaticle GitHub or in the community: https://github.com/vaticle/typedb-client-python